# Why does Android Studio 0.4.6 not create the extra resource directories? (e.g. values-v11, values-v14, etc)

Tags: android-studio

**Questions**

Why does Android Studio v0.4.6 not create addition values directories with qualifiers like earlier versions do?

Have I missed a setting or explanation of why this has changed?

**Extra Details**

I was just watching a training video (see http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/android-dotnet-developers-android-studio) and I noticed it had a res directory structure like this:

```
├───res
│   ├───drawable-hdpi
│   ├───drawable-mdpi
│   ├───drawable-xhdpi
│   ├───drawable-xxhdpi
│   ├───layout
│   ├───menu
│   ├───values
│   ├───values-sw600dp
│   ├───values-sw720dp-land
│   ├───values-v11
│   ├───values-v14
```

That video was using version v0.1.1 and had just created a project from scratch.  I've seen this directory structure before while trying out Android development with the ADT in Eclipse.

When I create a new project with version v0.4.6 (I downloaded it yesterday, 2014-03-23) I get this directory structure:

```
├───res
│   ├───drawable-hdpi
│   ├───drawable-mdpi
│   ├───drawable-xhdpi
│   ├───drawable-xxhdpi
│   ├───layout
│   ├───menu
│   ├───values
│   ├───values-w820dp
```

I've tried different settings in the new project wizard for API levels but that doesn't seem to change this setup.  I tried searching in various places:

- [Android Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=label%3aSubcomponent-Tools-Studio&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&cells=tiles)
- [Source code for Android Studio (at least I think so)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/studio/cloud)
- [Android Tools Project Site - Recent Changes](http://tools.android.com/recent)
- [Android Tools Project Site - Known Issues](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)
- Here on Stackoverflow
- And the internet in general via Google search

I couldn't find anything that explained why it had suddenly changed from creating the extra values directories to creating just one extra directory.  I attempted to look for the source code of Android Studio but I having never looked at it before I think that might be a bit hard to find something like this.  It's not like they will have 'res/values' or 'res/values-v11' hard coded (at least you hope not) so it's not going to be easy to just find where the values get created.

Comment: It still is this way as of AS 0.8 Beta.  I wonder what's so special about w820dp?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create the directories yourself. It would be a little overwhelming to set up a new project and have it create a ton of directories for configurations you'll never need.

Comment: I did think that when I came back to Android recently.  It was about v2.1 when I last tried it, I'm sure there were far less files in a new project.  I guess since its still a preview release you have to accept some changes that might not be fully explained until the stable release.